# Get(int) asp.net wep api

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, get

I really confused with my web api now. Here is my code for Get method:

```
public Employee Get(int id)
{
            using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
            {
                return entities.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID==id);
            }
        }
```

And I use jquery ajax to get that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/employees/1',
            method: 'GET',

            success: function (data) {
                $('#ul').empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    var row = $('<tr><td>' + value.ID + '</td><td>'
                        + value.FirstName + '</td><td>'
                        + value.LastName + '</td><td>'
                        + value.Gender + '</td><td>'
                        + value.Salary + '</td></tr>');
                    $('#ul').append(row);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

when I ran it, it just returned lots of 'undefined'. However when I run "http://localhost:52178/api/employees/1" in browser, I got the right xml I want. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the URL in your Ajax call to "/api/employees/1" - which has the leading slash

Comment: I found the problem! It's not the url, it is the function of success: function(data). Inside the function, it doesn't have to do $.each, just append the data with its properties.

Comment: @MinxuanZhang great! Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Use   `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` in ajax options

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'api/employees/1',
        method: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",/*use this option*/
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ul').empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                var row = $('<tr><td>' + value.ID + '</td><td>'
                    + value.FirstName + '</td><td>'
                    + value.LastName + '</td><td>'
                    + value.Gender + '</td><td>'
                    + value.Salary + '</td></tr>');
                $('#ul').append(row);
            });
        }
    });
```